# problema al ordenar listview

Tags: c#, listview

hola estoy teniendo problemas cuando yo ordeno por columna y luego quiero agregar un item o volver a listar los datos me larga este mensaje :"Invalid argument= El valor de 1 no es válido para index. Nombre del parametro index.

El problema ocurre cuando se cambia el orden de los datos en el listview y al querer listar denuevo lanza una excepcion de indice no válido, debido a que no se por qué razón cada vez que va listar llama al metodo "compare" de la clase ListViewItemComparer y ahi es donde crashea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un código de ejemplo para que puedan ver el error:
[Código de ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/fergorraiz/dbf3f0a9a7ae9a9afc031ecb00eaf060)

Comment: pero el error se presenta dentro de la clase ListViewItemComparer o en el evento ColumnClick

Comment: @LeandroTuttini se produce dentro de la clase ListViewItemComparer , el evento columnclick anda bien, el tema es cuando quiero listar denuevo y el orden de las columnas fue alterado entonces no se porque razon salta del metodo listar al metodo "compare" de la clase ListViewItemCompare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta modificar en la función listar la manera en que añades los elementos, que quede de esta manera:

```
for(int num=0;num<=3;num++)
{
  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
  item.Text = num.ToString();
  item.SubItems.Add(nombres[num]);
  item.SubItems.Add(apellidos[num]);
  listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: increiblemente funciona haciendolo como dices pero no entiendo por qué jaja, cual seria la diferencia de llenar el listado como lo hacia yo a como lo planteas vos?

Comment: La diferencia es que insertes los subitems en el item del listview antes de añadirlo al listview, como lo hacias era que insertabas al listview el item y posteriormente le añadias los subitems

Comment: Si te funciono por favor marcala como correcta para los que vengan detras de ti :)